Draw a tree using D3.js and then connect two arbitrary nodes (not adjacent in the tree)
I have no problems drawing the tree corresponding to hierarchical object. But I can't to figure out how to connect to some non-adjacent nodes by line... What's the best way to do this?

Here is the code fragment I have (except I haven't added any dashed line).
Let's suppose that I know the names of some two nodes I want to connect.
        let root = d3.hierarchy(obj);
        
        let treeLayout = d3.tree().size([700, 220])
        treeLayout(root);
      
        // Links
        d3.select('svg g')
            .selectAll('line')
            .data(root.links())
            .join('line')
            .attr('x1', function(d) {return d.source.x;})
            .attr('y1', function(d) {return d.source.y;})
            .attr('x2', function(d) {return d.target.x;})
            .attr('y2', function(d) {return d.target.y;});
        
        // Nodes
        d3.select('svg g')
            .selectAll('circle')
            .data(root.descendants())
            .join('circle')
            .attr('cx', function(d) {return d.x;})
            .attr('cy', function(d) {return d.y;})
            .attr('r', 4);
  


        let findNodeCoordsByName = function(name) {
          for (let i = 0; i < root.descendants().length; i++) {
            if (root.descendants()[i].data.name === name) {
              return [root.descendants()[i].x, root.descendants()[i].y];
            }
          }
        };

This allows one to find coordinates of specific node by its name. And then one can add necessary line between two specific nodes.
